# Can you add a menu item to be a sibling of FILE..ABOUT using a vs extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I want to have my extension add a menu item to the right of the about in visual studio.

I am using vs2017

I have found these are the lists of places you can add
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx

Here is how I added it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165473.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Here is my vsct:

```
<Menus>
        <Menu guid="guidCustomCommandPackageCmdSet" id="TopLevelMenu" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
            <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu"
                    id="IDM_VS_TOOL_MAINMENU" />
            <Strings>
                <ButtonText>TestMenu</ButtonText>
                <CommandName>TestMenu</CommandName>
            </Strings>
        </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Groups>
        <Group guid="guidWarmToquePackageCmdSet1" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
            <Parent guid="guidCustomCommandPackageCmdSet" id="TopLevelMenu" />
        </Group>
    </Groups>
```

Comment: Where you really want to add the menu item? Sorry for that not very sure that what is the "The right of the about in VS", the default Fire or Help menu or custom menu? In addition, would you please share the real issue you get in your side during you add your menu item?

Comment: Look at the top of visual studio.  Do you see the about menu item.  How do I put my new menu item to the right of about.

Comment: I didn't find it in my side, can you share a screen shot about it? Can you add your menu to the top of the VS IDE? If you just want to change the menu location, generally we could change it in the Customize window for all menu bars.

Comment: I can not add menus to the top of the IDE, that's what I want to do.  DO you know a reference or example how to do that?

Comment: @RJ Thompson, My understanding is that you want to add your menu to the specific location under the top of the VS IDE menu. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ef8da65-4fd0-400a-ae02-4bd9875bc2d8/how-do-i-add-a-custom-menu-item-at-the-end-visual-studio-main-menu-items?forum=vsx

Comment: So your saying it can't be done?